# Redirect to parent via iFrame from MVC Action using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC form in an iFrame on a Webforms site. The form submits via the following code but I would like it to redirect to the parent page on the Webforms site. It doesn’t work as I can’t get RedirectResult to target the parent. From what I have learnt in the past is that it can’t be done?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string FindText, string FindTown)
{
    return new RedirectResult("http://www.thesite.com/SearchResults.aspx?SearchText=" + SearchText + "&Town=" + Town);
}
```

Is there a way I can target the parent via Javascript from inside the Action to achieve the result I would like?

e.g.. using,

```
window.parent.location.href
```

if this is possible how would I write it?

Answer (score 6):

You can try return JavaScriptResult:

```
return new JavaScriptResult 
{
    Script = string.Format("window.parent.location.href = '{0}'", url)
};
```

or ContentResult:

```
return ContentResult
{
    Content = string.Format("<script type="text/javascript">window.parent.location.href = '{0}';</script>", url),
    ContentType = "text/html"
};
```